# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - react -rainbow-components@^1.31.0 is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-rainbow-components

I'm using the react rainbow components in our project, while running

> npm i react-rainbow-components

**I am getting npm error 404 'react -rainbow-components@^1.31.0 is not in the npm registry**.Although upon checking at [npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rainbow-components) it shows the package details . I also tried setting registry as

> npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: What navigator are you using ? And what it's version

Comment: I am using it on Windows and the node version is 14

Comment: No ! I'm. Talking about what version of navigator ( chrome , safari , firfox ...)